# Rounded corners in IE , long selectors? (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, rounded-corners

I used DD_roundies plugin which is rounding corners in elements, but it's works only with 1 selector, for example $('#element').addRule('10px'); and it's well done, but when I use selection kind of $('#element .class .class div span').addRule('10px'); it doesn't work. So maybe someone knowes this issue, how to fix it or maybe anybody knowes better way to make corners are rounded, any better plugins.

Comment: does the second selector return more than one element?

Answer (score 0):

You can CSS to create rounded corners (e.g. http://davidwalsh.name/css-rounded-corners )

Answer (score 0):

You can try this "**progressive internet explorer**" http://css3pie.com/